# JSON Formatting of Log Messages

Tags: json, logging, .net-core, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging in order to write log messages to AWS Cloudwatch.

The setup of this is as below:

**Program.cs**

```
        var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
            {
                configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
            {

                hostContext.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.Split(',')[0];
                configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
                configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.development.json", optional: true);


            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) =>
            {
                configLogging.AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                configLogging.AddConsole();
                configLogging.AddDebug();

                if (useCloudWatchLogs)
                    configLogging.AddAWSProvider(hostContext.Configuration.GetAWSLoggingConfigSection());

                configLogging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
            });
```

My calls to logging (injected into other classes) looks like this:

```
_log.LogInformation("Subscription Created. ID: " + subscriptionId);
```

When I view the logs in Cloudwatch, I get the single line string exactly as per the call to LogInformation().

What I would like to to log as a structured JSON object, looking something like below:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-09-13T16:10:03.488399Z",
    "level": "INFO",
    "pid": 1,
    "thread_id": 140388289685248,
    "message": "Creating a Kafka consumer with params: {'bootstrap.servers': 'myservers', 'security.protocol': 'PLAINTEXT', 'group.id': 'my-group', 'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'}"
}
```

Where everything other than message is done by the formatter.  The message is whatever is passed from the call to log.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this (or if it is possible?)

I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging from .Net Core.  Also using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a custom formatter allows me to do this.  Code becomes:

```
Func<LogLevel, object, Exception, string> logFormatter = (a, b, c) => "{\"Hello from\":\"GinjaNinja\"}";
```

And then in plumbing:

```
configLogging.AddAWSProvider(hostContext.Configuration.GetAWSLoggingConfigSection(), formatter:logFormatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Absolutely. You can even [filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) them for analytics.**

When you call `LogInformation` just pass a serialized and formatted JSON and you are good to go.

A good approach would be to create an object to do logging logic instead of putting inside your main object, then pass it into `LogInformation`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm hoping that there is a way to provide a formatter in the setup rather than changing every log call.

Comment: @GinjaNinja You can achieve that if you create your own custom formatter class, which would be used as a middle class to format your log before calling the real log formatter, I'll be updating my answer with some sample code if I have time.

Comment: That sounds ideal.  If you are able to provide some sample of code and wiring I will accept answer